# How to add authorized IP to private GKE cluster using gcloud CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

We are using a private GKE cluster on autopilot and every time I have to connect with kubectl, I have to add my IP to the control plane authorized networks using the UI interface.
Can this be done using gcloud, so it is faster/can be automated?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72344186/6064933

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for that

```
gcloud container clusters update <clusterName> --master-authorized-networks=....
```

Comment: I saw this, but does it make sure that I update only my IP and don't delete/modify the IP of my colleagues (there are multiple entries present)?

Comment: Adding yours doesn't delete your colleagues'

Comment: With this approach, if I only specify my IP, all the others are overwritten, so I have to specify all IPs every time. Moreover, I can't use the displayName here, so the labels are lost. Can you give an example if it is not like this?

Comment: Add an authorized network to an existing cluster using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#gcloud):
`gcloud container clusters create cluster-name \
    --enable-master-authorized-networks \
    --master-authorized-networks cidr1,cidr2...`
Where cluster-name: is the name of your existing cluster.
 cidr1, cidr2: The CIDR values for the authorized networks. We can add “n” number of cidr values by using commas to separate them.