# How to append new ip in existing authorized network list on google cloud kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Right now, I can add my ip using

```
gcloud container clusters update core-cluster --zone=asia-southeast1-a --enable-master-authorized-networks --master-authorized-networks w.x.y.z/32
```

but it overrides all the existing authorized networks that was already there.

Is there any way to append the new ip to the existing list of authorized networks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could automate what @Gari Singh said using gcloud, jq and tr. See below for doing it with CLI:

```bash
NEW_CIDR=8.8.4.4/32
export CLUSTER=test-psp
OLD_CIDR=$(gcloud container clusters describe $CLUSTER --format json | jq -r '.masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig.cidrBlocks[] | .cidrBlock' | tr '\n' ',')
echo "The existing master authorized networks were $OLD_CIDR"
gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER --master-authorized-networks "$OLD_CIDR$NEW_CIDR" --enable-master-authorized-networks
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  Meant to come back and add similar.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Can we add the network name as well? Name will be helpful when I want to remove my old ips.

Comment: I didn't see that option in CLI help output

Answer (score 2):

No.  You'll need to first get the current value, append that to the additional value and then update with the new aggregate list.